# How to connect elements from two separate divs?

Tags: html, css, hover

I've been trying to connect a link with an image so that when the link is hovered, img tag switches to visibility:visible from visibility:hidden. I gave them both IDs and I've placed them in separate divs. The problem lies that I can't seem to manage to affect img tag with the a tag no matter how I try just because they are in separate divs. I have tried by using > and + properties but that does not work because they are not related.

Is it possible to do this?

Example:

```
<div id = "something1"> <a href = "something.html" id = "somethingLink"> Word </a> </div>
<div id = "something2"> <img src = "something.jpg" id = "somethingImage"/> </div>
```

Comment: Not impossible but it will depend on the actual HTML. Can you provide a JSfiddle? JS/Jquery would be simplest though.

Comment: This can be done very simply in jQuery, I've added an answer below. If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use JS.

Change your selector's

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6AT77/)

```
#something1:hover  ~ #something2 img {
    visibility: visible;
}

#something2 img {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Shame on me, always so quick to resort to JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$("#somethingLink").hover(
function(){$("#somethingImage").css("visibility","visible");},
function(){$("#somethingImage").css("visibility","hidden");}
)
```

Comment: Not sure this is correct, and you've spelled visibility wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this:

```
$('#somethingLink').hover(function(){
    $('#somethingImage').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Just make sure `#somethingImage` is set to `visibility: hidden;` in your CSS.